# LINQ Combobox Databinding behave weird

Tags: linq, data-binding, combobox

I'm having a WinForm on witch I've a DataGridView that display a list of sites. bellow that grid i've a TextBox and a Combobox, using DataBinding the textbox show the current value "Code" grid column and the combobox show the province. The combobox is filled with a list for province
The weird thing is this:
When I change the combobox selected province for another one, at the time when the focus leave the combobox, the original value of the of the combobox return. I can't find a way for the combobox to keep the changed value.

what am I doing wrong?

Here my the code of my workbench project;

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context = new GMR_DEVEntities();
        lSite = from t in context.tblSites where t.Actif == true select t;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = lSite;

        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        Guid ProvinceId = Guid.Parse("00000000-0001-0000-0008-000000000001");

        IQueryable<tblDomVal> provinces = from prov in context.tblDomVals where prov.pTypeDomValID == ProvinceId select prov;

        comboBox1.DataSource = provinces;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DescrFr";

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", lSite, "Code"));

        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", lSite, "pProvinceID", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));


    }
```

Any help would be welcome :)

Hugo

Comment: Do you perhaps notice that the lSite query is executed more often than expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for a solution, I've discover that the problem have something to do with the Datatype (All my tables IDs are GUID), I've change the Binding to bind with a varchar field instead of the guid, and thing went good. So the problem have something to do with GUID. But I'll change my approach, and work with manual bind

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new binding context for you combo

```
 BindingContext oBC = new BindingContext();
    comboBox1.BindingContext = oBC;
    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", lSite, "pProvinceID", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: Well, i've try it but the behavior has not changed, still the original value return when the focus, leave the control. :(

Comment: do you have some kind of event related with your combobox?

Comment: No, the code that you see above is the only code in the form. And the combobox are no custom one.

Comment: I've notice something, in the **Validating** events, the "Combobox.Selectedvalue" is goods, I mean it is corresponding to the changed one, but in the **Validated** event, the "Combobox.Selectedvalue" is the Original one.

Comment: validated event always is fired up after validating event, so if validated sets your combo to an unwanted value then that's the cause of your problem

Comment: What happens is that I do not change the value, in either Validating nor validated, I was just monitoring it. Something else is changing it, and I don't know what.

Comment: While searching for a solution, I've discover that the problem have something to do with the Datatype (All my tables IDs are GUID), I've change the Binding to bind with a varchar field instead of the guid, and thing went good. So the problem have something to do with GUID. But I'll change my approach, and work with manual bind